# javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder strange behavior

Tags: java, json

I am creating `JsonArrayBuilder` using `JsonBuilderFactory` and trying to add two `JsonObject` into it.
After the loop is over, JsonArrayBuilder.build method is returning same (duplicates) objects.

Example:

```
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null);                                             
JsonArrayBuilder array_builder = factory.createArrayBuilder();                                             
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)                                                                                       
{                                                                                                               
    JsonObjectBuilder json_Builder = factory.createObjectBuilder();                                                   
    json_Builder.add("Key", "Val_"+i);                                                                                   

    array_builder.add(json_Builder.build());                                                                   
}                                                                                                         
JsonArray json_Array = array_builder.build();                // this producing same two json objects              
                                                             //with same key and value                      
System.out.println("Result - "+ json_Array.toString());
```

Output :

```
[                                           
  {                                     
      "Key":"Val_1"                                                   
  },                                                            
  {                                                              
      "Key":"Val_1"                                                       
  }                                                      
]
```

Getting this wired behavior on some machine, I checked the machine with this behavior installed `openJDK 1.8.0_212` ( hope this is not the problem ).

Can you please help me understand why this objects getting duplicate ?

Comment: Don't you need to move the builder outside the for loop?

Comment: What JSON libraries are you using BTW?

Comment: I am using javax.json

Comment: what is your _expected_ output? Because it looks ok to me: objects in an array.

Comment: //Expected behavior :                      
[                                           
  {                                     
      "Key":"Val_0"                                                   
  },                                                            
  {                                                              
      "Key":"Val_1"                                                       
  }                                                      
]